# Is it better to use LIFO order or FIFO order when keeping a list of freed blocks in a dynamic memory allocator?

Tags: c, list, malloc, fifo

I'm trying to implement malloc() in C for class, and I can't decide whether a block should be added to the end of the free list or the head of the free list. Which would be better, and why? The list I'm using is a doubly linked list and (for now) is unordered.

Answer (score 4):

Without running a benchmark, the most likely choice to give best performance is FIFO, i.e. put freed blocks at the head of the free list.

This is because FIFO is most likely to provide [temporal locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), because a just-freed block is more likely to reside in a CPU cache than a block freed earlier and not used for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two shouldn't be obvious (if there is one): the order in which blocks are allocated and freed depends of a user (the programmer who's using your malloc), thus you can consider it as random.

Make at least an ordered list by sizes.

Take a look at some other techniques if you really want something fast, For instance, implement a [buddy system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, my textbook mentions that maintaining the list in address order enjoys better memory utilization than a list in LIFO order when the allocator uses a first fit algorithm, but it doesn't explain why. Does it make it easier to coalesce the blocks, or is there a different reason?